# Coding help for Arduino RFID activated Anti-Bike-Theft System

Tags: arduino, rfid

I am super new to coding and Arduino and I was wondering if you could help me with my code.
I am trying to make a RFID activated bike theft alarm. I started with the basics of coding a system activated and deactivated by an RFID transponder. However I seem to not be able to code the activation and deactivation right, as the system deactivates right after activating. 
I hope you can help. Thanks in advance.
My code is:

```
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
int ledPin = 4;

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); 

void setup() 
{
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);  
 SPI.begin();      
 mfrc522.PCD_Init();   
 Serial.println("Approximate your card to the reader...");
 Serial.println();

}
void loop() 
{
 // Look for new cards
 if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
 {
   return;
 }

 if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
 {
   return;
 }

 Serial.print("UID tag :");
 String content= "";
 byte letter;
 for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
 {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
 }
 Serial.println();
 Serial.print("Message : ");
 content.toUpperCase();
 if (content.substring(1) == "8A BC 91 79")
 {
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
   Serial.println("Lock activated");
   Serial.println();
   delay(3000); 
 }

 Serial.println();
 Serial.print("Message : ");
 content.toUpperCase();
 if ((digitalWrite == ledPin, HIGH) and (content.substring(1) == "8A BC 91 79"))
 {
   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
   Serial.println("Lock deactivated");
   Serial.println();
   delay(3000);
 }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "deactivates right after activating". no 3 second delay? why do you activate every time and not only when the lock is deactivated?

Comment: Hey Piglet, thanks for taking interest in my problem. I suppose I didn't express myself correctly. What I meant was that I want the "lock" to activate when I put the RFID chip onto the reader and then to stay activated until I again put the chip onto the reader. In the end the whole project should be a RFID chip activated and deactivated bike alarm triggered by movement measured by a gyroscope. I am sorry if my questions are stupid. Like I said in my original post, I am quite new to coding.

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve. I still don't know if there is a 3 second delay befor the lock unlocks again. you say "right after" but your code has a delay. if you want to have your lock locked you should not unlock it after 3 seconds.

Comment: There is a delay of about 3 seconds after the lock locks and then it unlocks after these 3 seconds. When i remove the delay command it straight away unlocks and the again locks continuously as the chip is in the proximity of the reader.